# Null Records Triggering Else Statement Incorrectly

Tags: javascript, datetime, if-statement

I have a function that creates a slug for two of my database properties, but I want it to return the slug of the two values together only if a data is present for a record. To create this logic I decided to create and if/else statement that looks to find if there is a null value for both fields and then renders if a statement is true or false. I have a few records with null values, but they are still triggering the "Statement false" console.log and I can't understand why. When I console log the variables on their own I get null for those records. Any reason why my statement isn't working?

Console logs:

```
null //startDateValue no value
null //endDateValue no value
Statement false //Wrong conclusion. "Statement true" should have been triggered
Sat Mar 05 2016 19:00:00 GMT-0500 (EST)
Thu Apr 07 2016 20:00:00 GMT-0400 (EDT)
Statement false //Correct conclusion. Both values are present
```

Function:

```
dataDateRangeSlug: function(){
            var startDateValue = this.getDataValue('dataDateStart'); 
            var startDate = new Date(startDateValue); 
            var momentStartDate = moment(startDate).utc().format("MM/DD/YYYY");

            var endDateValue = this.getDataValue('dataDateEnd');
            var endDate = new Date(endDateValue);
            var momentEndDate = moment(endDate).utc().format("MM/DD/YYYY");

            console.log(startDateValue);
            console.log(endDateValue);

            if (startDateValue && endDateValue == null){
                console.log("Statement true");
            } else {
                console.log("Statement false");
                return momentStartDate + ' - ' + momentEndDate;
            }           
        },
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if (startDateValue && endDateValue == null){
    console.log("Statement true");
}
```

This condition is verified when startDateValue is set and endDateValue is null.

You can correct it by this :

```
if (startDateValue == null && endDateValue == null){
    console.log("Statement true");
}
```

The `&&` is an `AND` between two conditions, you can't use it to check both variables are null as you do it.